# Why would Power PC mac stop being able to charge and not respond to power button?

Tags: 16.04, mate, powerpc

As per [this page of Ubuntu MATE](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.04/release/), it says that for the "Mac (PowerPC) and IBM-PPC (POWER5) desktop image -- For Apple Macintosh G3, G4, and G5 computers, including iBooks and PowerBooks as well as older IBM OpenPower 7xx machines" there's a specific Ubuntu MATE image.  Because of this, I used that image for live booting. My PowerMac was already running Ubuntu 10.4. After 15 minutes of seemingly booting up into the Ubuntu MATE 16.04 live mode, the laptop froze. Then after 30 minutes of realizing that nothing was happening, I powered off by holding down the power button. Now the computer won't even respond to the charger -- no charge light upon plug in -- nor will it respond to pressing the power button. What could be the problem??

Comment: try power cycling it

Comment: @SuiciDoga the OP states "nor will it respond to pressing the power button"

Comment: still you should be able to power cycle it by removing the battery and holding the power button down for 1 minute and leaving it for 1 hour and then trying. doing this fixed an hp laptop that would blink caps lock and not boot. maybe powermac is different but im sure google can help

Comment: Hi, I ended up waiting a week, following your instructions (1. removing battery, 2. holding down power for 1 minute, and 3. waiting one hour before turning on), and also then replacing the old battery with a new one. This worked. I was then able to use the same UBUNTU MATE disk to boot into live mode, except that now I have to figure out how to make the touch pad responsive. :)

Comment: Anyways, Thanks for the tips. It solved my problem of not responding to the charger or the power button.